# SQL Server - Update statement with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-update

I have this table Tree:

```
ID  Name   ParentID
-------------------
1   A      NULL
2   A B    1
3   A B C  2
```

I want to trim the parent prefix in the name column (in my example above 'A' in the second row and 'A-B' in the third), the parent might be multiple words for simplicity I just put a letter in my example.

```
Update 
    Tree
Set 
    Name = REPLACE(Name,
    (Select Name 
     Where ParetnID=@ParentID), '')
Where ParentId IS NOT NULL
```

Im not sure how the get that `@ParentID`

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn SQL Server V17.1

Comment: ooops... can you confirm if the parentid is the ID itself?

Comment: Where'd you get that number? Is that from SSMS? Try running `SELECT @@Version`. What does that return?

Comment: @Shawn its SSMS 17, SQL Server 2016

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes, the ParentID is the ID of another row.

Comment: @ArenSargsyans see my updated answer.

Comment: Since it's 2016, you may be able to use `STRING_SPLIT()` and then get the last column. Your database has to be at Compatibility Level 130 though.

Comment: @ArenSargsyans  you will have to re-write your OP... and put the NAME field is actually the Parent's Name referenced from ParentID to ID... people are trying to solve the string issue where it is not.

Answer (score 1):

try use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) Function, it enables to access a row that comes before the current row.

```
    DECLARE @ttable TABLE
        (
          id SMALLINT ,
          name VARCHAR(10) ,
          parentid SMALLINT
        )

    INSERT  INTO @ttable
    VALUES  ( 1, 'A', NULL ),
            ( 2, 'A B', 1 ),
            ( 3, 'A B C', 2 )

    --
            ;
            WITH    CTE
                      AS ( SELECT   Id ,
                                    name ,
                                    RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(name, LAG(name, 1, 0) OVER ( ORDER BY id ), ''))) rr ,
                                    parentid
                           FROM     @ttable
                         )
                UPDATE  CTE
                SET     name = rr


 SELECT  * FROM @ttable
```

Result

```
    id     name       parentid
    ------ ---------- --------
    1      A          NULL
    2      B          1
    3      C          2

    (3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: +1 even though I did thought about using cte but this is neat approach. I like cte's though my answer use subquery

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @t TABLE (ID INT ,  Name VARCHAR(100),   ParentID INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1   ,'A'      ,NULL),
(2   ,'A B'    ,1   ),
(3   ,'A B C'  ,2   )
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM @t t 
    CROSS APPLY 
            (
            SELECT   Replace(
                        RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')))
                        ,'|' , '&') NameElement
                 ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 NodeLevel
            FROM 
             (
                SELECT Cast ('<X>' 
                            + Replace(Replace(t.Name, ' ', '</X><X>'), '&' , '|') 
                            + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
              ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
            ) c(NameElement, NodeLevel)
WHERE t.ParentID = c.NodeLevel
```

**Result Set**

```
+----+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| ID | Name  | ParentID | NameElement | NodeLevel |
+----+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|  2 | A B   |        1 | B           |         1 |
|  3 | A B C |        2 | C           |         2 |
+----+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

**SQL Server 2016 and Later versions**

In SQL Server 2016 STRING_SPLIT() function has made this a lot simpler. In SQL Server 2016 and later versions your query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM @t t 
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT value 
                     ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 NodeLevel
               FROM string_split(t.name , ' ')
            ) c(NameElement, NodeLevel)
WHERE t.ParentID = c.NodeLevel
```

Now you can convert this select into an update statement.

Comment: I gave an example data up there so the parent is not 1 character(A), parent prefix is longer, I want to get that rows parent name in a variable and trim the variable out from that row name.Does that make sense?

Comment: For future readers, `ROW_NUMBER()` will only work in SQL2016+ if the Compatibility Level is 130+. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Update NAME (aka Parent's Name) from the parent reference. The OP is confusing since NAME field was not explained.

```
update t
set name = (select top 1 name from tree m where t.parentid = m.id)
from tree t
```

demo here
http://rextester.com/live/SXLC53543

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, in my real data I don't have any separator I just put it there to be clear, I will fix my question.

Comment: if you want to exclude nulls just put a where clause at the bottom but i think you will need nulls as this is your parent reference.

Comment: Change `replace(name,'-','.')` to `replace(name,' ','.')`. The separator is the space character.

Comment: actually @Shawn, the string is not the issue here... it's actually picking up the ID which relates to the Parent ID

Comment: Yes, but doesn't this only get rid of the first delimiter in the string? `A B C` will become `B C`?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fe18/1

Comment: yes.. your fiddle is correct.. i think the OP is incomplete.. the NAME is actually the Parent's NAME. that is what he's try to update.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes, it is the parent name maybe I was not clear enough, and this solution won't work since they might have multiple children and the inner select statement will return multiple rows since they have the same ParentID.

Comment: @ArenSargsyans maybe multiple parents... in this case which one will you pick or do you put all the parents name against the child?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    Update Tree
      Set Name = REPLACE(Name,B.Name, '')
    FROM Tree A
    INNER JOIN Tree B
    ON A.ParentID = B.ID
    Where ParentId IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Values can be simply selected by this way:

```
select substring(cv,CHARINDEX(pv,cv)+LEN(pv),LEN(cv)) 
from (select ct.name cv,pt.name pv from tree ct,tree pt where pt.id=ct.parentid) r
```

here t is your tree table. r is the subquery by joining with itself.
c prefix for child and p for parent.
must work

Answer (score 0):

Since you're SQL2016, you can make this easier by using some of the functions available there. This should work back to SQL2012, or SQL2008 if you change the `IIF()`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19e6e/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( ID int, Name varchar(10), ParentID int ) ;
INSERT INTO t 
VALUES 
    (1,'A1',NULL)
  , (2,'A1 B2',1)
  , (3,'A1 B2 C3',2)
  , (4,'D1',NULL)
  , (5,'D1 E2',4)
  , (6,'D1 E2 F3',5)
;
```

**The Query**:

```
SELECT s1.Name
  , REVERSE( IIF( s1.delim-1<0 , s1.revStr, LEFT(s1.revStr,(s1.delim-1)) ) ) AS finalStr
FROM (
  SELECT Name
    , REVERSE(t.Name) as revStr
    , CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE( t.Name )) as delim
  FROM t
) s1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19e6e/1/0)**:

```
|     Name | finalStr |
|----------|----------|
|       A1 |       A1 |
|    A1 B2 |       B2 |
| A1 B2 C3 |       C3 |
|       D1 |       D1 |
|    D1 E2 |       E2 |
| D1 E2 F3 |       F3 |
```

What I Did:

1) `FROM (...) s1` >> I used a subquery to keep from having to calculate the reversed string and the position of the delimiter.

1a) If the delimiter changes, just change `CHARINDEX(' ',.....)`.

2) Since I have the reversed string, I calculate the position of the delimiter and extract that string with `LEFT(s1.revStr,(s1.delim-1))`.

3) Since there may be only one element in the string (parent rows), I `IIF()` to see if my delimiter starts out of bounds.

4) Since I've extracted the first item of the reversed string, I now have to reverse that string back to revert to the original value.

Comment: I don't know how this will scale with a lot of rows or long Names. You'll have to check.

Comment: If you want to `UPDATE` the original table rather than `SELECT` from it, you can use this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/700a3/1